# When to use redis for better optimization?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, redis

I am beginner in redis and had used it in my node.js project and its providing good results when I see the caching mechanism it's been spinning

So basically in world where MySql,firebase and mongodb are top in there perspective, where would redis fit? Can we use redis for better optimization replacing any of these most popular databases or can have greater application role with specific technologies ? Maybe it should be used with javascript and its framework(eg. node.js has good analogy with redis) more?

Comment: "nosql" is not a database.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ya missed json instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is widely used for caching. Meaning, in a high availability infrastructure, when some data has to be accessed many times, you would store it in your database and then store it in redis with some unique key which you could rebuild easily with parameters. When the data is updated, you just clear that key in redis and add it again with the new data.

Example:

You have thousands of users. 
They all connect many many times and go on their profile. 
You might want to store their profile info in redis with a key `{userid}_user_info`.

The user tries to access his profile: 
   first check if data exists in redis, 
       if yes return it,
       else get it from db and insert it in redis

The user updates his profile info, just refresh the redis value. 
etc.

---

There is also another way redis is used, it's for queuing tasks and synchronising websockets broadcasts across machines. Here is a useful article about it 
http://fiznool.com/blog/2016/02/24/building-a-simple-message-queue-with-redis/

---

As per using redis as a database, well for simple data it can be used, like settings where a simple key/value is enough. For storing complex data, it's a bit of a hassle, specially if you want to use relational functionalities, or searching features. Redis is fast because it does not have all these features, and keeps data in memory (not only, but it does contribute).